# Compare dates using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have two dates (datetimes):

*date1 = 2010-12-31 15:13:48.593* 
*date2 = 2010-12-31 00:00:00.000*

It's the same day, just different times. Comparing date1 and date2 using <= doesn’t work because of the date1 time. So date1 <= date2 is wrong, but it should be true. Can I compare them by just looking at the year, month and day so they are the same? It's SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? In what context are you doing this comparison (if you are comparing against columns you need to take care to keep things sargable)?

Comment: I am doing this in a "select case". If the dates are <= do this, if not, do that. Its SQL Server 2008

Comment: For the comparison to fail, it seems that your date are stored as strings. If they were stored as datetime, I guess the comparison

Comment: date1 <= date2 = true? how is 3PM is less than 12AM?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(date1 AS DATE) <= CAST(date2 AS DATE) ...
```

Should do what you need.

### Test Case

```
WITH dates(date1, date2, date3, date4)
     AS (SELECT CAST('20101231 15:13:48.593' AS DATETIME),
                CAST('20101231 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME),
                CAST('20101231 15:13:48.593' AS DATETIME),
                CAST('20101231 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME))
SELECT CASE
         WHEN CAST(date1 AS DATE) <= CAST(date2 AS DATE) THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END AS COMPARISON_WITH_CAST,
       CASE
         WHEN date3 <= date4 THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END AS COMPARISON_WITHOUT_CAST
FROM   dates
```

Returns

```
COMPARISON_WITH_CAST   |  COMPARISON_WITHOUT_CAST
Y                         N
```

Comment: Note that the `DATE` type wasn't available before SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Luke - Yep. Hence my query as to what version the OP is on.

Comment: @grady - Yes it does! See test case this does exactly what you say you want!

Answer (score 74):

Use the [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function with a datepart of `day`.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, date1, date2) >= 0
```

Note that if you want to test that `date1` <= `date2` then you need to test that `DATEDIFF(day, date1, date2) >= 0`, or alternatively you could test `DATEDIFF(day, date2, date1) <= 0`.

Comment: This works, but can you pls explain why? Isnt that just comparing days?

Comment: @grady: Nope it counts the number of day *boundaries* between `date1` and `date2`; that is, the number of midnights you'd pass through to get from `date1` to `date2`

Comment: +1 Most elegant solution here. I'd consider ABS or <> 0 though if needed to allow for date2 before date1

Answer (score 4):

The simple one line solution is

```
datediff(dd,'2010-12-31 15:13:48.593','2010-12-31 00:00:00.000')=0

datediff(dd,'2010-12-31 15:13:48.593','2010-12-31 00:00:00.000')<=1

datediff(dd,'2010-12-31 15:13:48.593','2010-12-31 00:00:00.000')>=1
```

You can try various option with this other than "dd"

Answer (score 1):

I am always used DateDiff(day,date1,date2) to compare two date.

Checkout following example. Just copy that and run in Ms sql server.
Also, try with change date by 31 dec to 30 dec and check result

```
BEGIN

declare @firstDate datetime
declare @secondDate datetime


declare @chkDay int

set @firstDate ='2010-12-31 15:13:48.593'
set @secondDate ='2010-12-31 00:00:00.000'

set @chkDay=Datediff(day,@firstDate ,@secondDate )

if @chkDay=0
    Begin
        Print 'Date is Same'
    end
else
    Begin
        Print 'Date is not Same'
    end
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
BEGIN

declare @Date1 datetime
declare @Date2 datetime

declare @chkYear int
declare @chkMonth int
declare @chkDay int
declare @chkHour int
declare @chkMinute int
declare @chkSecond int
declare @chkMiliSecond int

set @Date1='2010-12-31 15:13:48.593'
set @Date2='2010-12-31 00:00:00.000'

set @chkYear=datediff(yyyy,@Date1,@Date2)
set @chkMonth=datediff(mm,@Date1,@Date2)
set @chkDay=datediff(dd,@Date1,@Date2)
set @chkHour=datediff(hh,@Date1,@Date2)
set @chkMinute=datediff(mi,@Date1,@Date2)
set @chkSecond=datediff(ss,@Date1,@Date2)
set @chkMiliSecond=datediff(ms,@Date1,@Date2)

if @chkYear=0 AND @chkMonth=0 AND @chkDay=0 AND @chkHour=0 AND @chkMinute=0 AND @chkSecond=0 AND @chkMiliSecond=0
    Begin
        Print 'Both Date is Same'
    end
else
    Begin
        Print 'Both Date is not Same'
    end
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below script in my SQL and it is working fine with me:

```
SELECT
    ID ,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ExpectedDate, ActualDate) < 0
        THEN 'Late'
        ELSE 'OnTime'
    END shipmentStatus
FROM orders
ORDER BY ExpectedDate
```