# Datetime cast in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, datetime

Why does

```
select cast('''1900-01-01''' as datetime)
```

fail in SQL Server 2005 ?

It's show error message :

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this code work? `SELECT CAST('19000101' AS DATETIME)` - no dashes in the string representing the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an invalid parameter. It should be

```
cast('1900-01-01' as datetime)
```

For more info See Here: [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [How to convert from string to datetime?](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Comment: Sorry, I mean cast ('''1900-01-01''' as datetime). It doesn't work

Comment: The 12-character string you are trying to convert begins and ends with apostrophes doesn't represent a valid datetime. Why should it work? (editing the original question to match your comment here).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794028/ms-sql-compare-dates