# MySQL Select rows where specified date is between start date and end date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My table has a column (datetime) for start date and time, "startdate", and a column (datetime) for end date and time, "endtime".

I want to select rows from the table where the startdate and enddate include a specified date.

Example: I have a row that has a startdate of 2014-06-22 20:00:00 and an enddate of 2014-06-29 23:00:00 and I want to select that row with the specified date range for a given day (2014-06-25).

Here is my query that is not currently doing what I want it to...

```
SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE `startdate` >= '2014-06-22 00:00:00' AND `enddate` <= '2014-06-22 23:59:59'
```

I have also tried the Between in the SQL query.  I think I am going to have to create a date range with the startdate and enddate and reference that from the specified date but I don't know how to do that.  Please help!

**EDIT:**

My table has 2 date columns.  I am injecting a specific day (2014-06-25).  I want to return rows that have a start date (startdate) before or on the specified day and an end date (enddate) after or on the specified date.  So basically I want active rows to show up based on a specified day.

Comment: Back again are we ;), this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4794081/1596244

Comment: What is the format of your startdate and enddate columns?

Comment: How is your current query not working?

Comment: The query above should work.

Comment: @Andrew because some of the start dates are the specified date or earlier and some of the end dates are the specified date or later.  I know the query is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean something like `<datetime parm> between STARTDATE and ENDDATE'?

Comment: shouldn't it be startdate <= and end date>= if your specified date is to be between the two. you are currently looking for rows that start after specified date and end before specified date which is probably impossible

Comment: @MarkD Yes, you're right.  I forgot to change it back after testing it the other way,  the query i provided still will not do what I want though.

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you for referring me to that question.  However, I am unable to get any of those answers to work properly.

Comment: why do you have startdate and enddate in quotes? I'm surprised you aren't getting errors from that query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690079/how-to-select-rows-if-given-date-is-between-two-dates open the above link for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp) function with a datepart of day.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, date1, date2) >= 0
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4794063/5900604)