# Compare two dates in c# by passing sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have a table named RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE which has a column named BUSINESSDATE which has date in format(yyyy-mm-dd) 2015-05-22.
I want to comapre this date with batch.StartDateTime of format (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss) 05-10-2015 12:09:03.

```
var dateAndTime = batch.StartDateTime;
var date = dateAndTime.ToShortDateString();
string query = "SELECT COUNT(discamount) AS DISCOUNTCOUNT "+
                " FROM ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE where "+
                "(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),BUSINESSDATE,105) >= '" + date
                + "') and DISCAMOUNT > 0
```

Using the above query gives me all the values of the column I just want the count of values greater than or equal to batch date

Comment: You should parametarize your query.

Comment: What is exactly the datatype of the column `BUSINESSDATE`?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Can you please explain that?

Comment: @Khonsort the datatype is Date

Comment: If it's a date datatype, the representation as written is not important. It's a date (just make the question unclear).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS SQL compare dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794028/ms-sql-compare-dates)

Comment: @GajendraRajput May be `var date = dateAndTime.ToShortDateString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: For parameterising queries, [see this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
var dateAndTime = batch.StartDateTime;
var date = dateAndTime.ToShortDateString();
string query = "SELECT COUNT(discamount) AS DISCOUNTCOUNT "+
            " FROM ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE "+
            " WHERE BUSINESSDATE >= CONVERT(DATE, '" + date + "', 105) 
            and DISCAMOUNT > 0 "
```

And, bonus, this use index on `BUSINESSDATE` if an index exist.

or better as @FelixPamittan said, use a prepared statement with binding :

```
var dateAndTime = batch.StartDateTime;
var date = dateAndTime.ToShortDateString();
string query = "SELECT COUNT(discamount) AS DISCOUNTCOUNT "+
            " FROM ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE "+
            " WHERE BUSINESSDATE >= :theDate 
            and DISCAMOUNT > 0 "
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick for you

```
var dateAndTime = batch.StartDateTime;
var date = dateAndTime.ToShortDateString();
string query = "SELECT COUNT(discamount) AS DISCOUNTCOUNT " +
                " FROM ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE WHERE" +
                "BUSINESSDATE > = (CONVERT(VARCHAR, " + @dateParam + " ,105) >= '" + 
                + "') and DISCAMOUNT > 0

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateParam", date.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of above answers I modified it and finally got the solution

```
var dateAndTime = batch.StartDateTime;
var date = dateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string query = "SELECT COUNT(discamount) AS DISCOUNTCOUNT "+
               " FROM ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE where "+                    
               "BUSINESSDATE >= '" + date + "'" + 
               " and DISCAMOUNT > 0
```

Comment: It's better to convert explicitaly with the format. use `CONVERT(DATE, '"+date+"', 120)` instead of `'"+date+"'`

Comment: But preparedStatement is the best ;-)